# Detecting intent in DialogFlow CX

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-cx

I am trying to detect an intent using the following code in nodeJS:

```
 const session=new dialogflow.SessionsClient({ project_id:"activity3-viod", keyFilename:"assets/keys/dialogflow.json" });    
 const sessionPath = session.projectLocationAgentSessionPath("activity3-viod","us-central1","Test-CX","123456789");
 const request = { session: sessionPath, queryInput:{ text: { text: "sample phrase", languageCode:"en-US" }}};    
 const responses = await session.detectIntent(request);
```

I get the following error:

> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Please switch to 'us-central1-dialogflow.googleapis.com' to access resources located in 'us-central1'.

The project is indeed  us-centra11 and I think the id and agent names are right.
They are what DF says on the site.
I thought I was addressing us-centra11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the regional API endpoint if you use Agents outside the `global` region. Check [the Python example here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api#detect-intent) which has an `if` clause to check for regions which are not `global`.

I think the Node.js example is missing the ClientOptions.